# How to see a SQL table's comment in CLI?

Tags: postgresql

Let say I have a schema world and a table city in a Postgres DB.
I can set a comment on the table (or view, function, index, ...) with the command below:

```
COMMENT ON TABLE world.city IS 'This is a test comment';
```

How can I see this comment in CLI (Not GUI)?
I tried using show command thinking it might help, but got a syntax error!

```
SHOW TABLE world.city;  
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "table"  
LINE 1: show table world.city;
```

The same happened with show command on views!

Comment: In `psql` (CLI) the command `\d+ world.city` will show that. `show table` isn't a valid SQL command [as documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-commands.html)

Comment: Even using `\d+` I can't see the comment I put for the table.

Comment: `select obj_description(oid) from pg_class where relname = 'city'`

Comment: This works, too. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 \d+ world.city
```

[From the documentation:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-META-COMMANDS)

The command form \d+ is identical, except that more information is displayed: any comments associated with the columns of the table are shown, as is the presence of OIDs in the table, the view definition if the relation is a view, a non-default replica identity setting and the access method name if the relation has an access method.

Comment: `\d+ world.city` works for me, not `{\d+ world.city}`  
However, I don't see the comment I just put there for world.city! Only the columns and their type and such.
The comment I put is not for a column, but the whole table.

Comment: Removed the {} from the code in my answer (was an accident). Try \dt+ world.city to see table comments

Comment: \dt+ worked, thank you.
What command is for the same on view and user-defined functions?
(Found \dv+ for the views)

Comment: I guess `\df+` for the functions.
How can I only show the description column, not all the others when using  `\df+` (or any other `\d`)?